# typeahead.js or bloodhound not working for me

Tags: javascript, mongodb, searchbar, twitter-typeahead

I'm not getting any suggestions. what am I missing

```
var states = new Bloodhound({
    // datumTokenizer : function(d){return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name) },
    datumTokenizer :  Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace("name"),
    queryTokenizer : Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    // local : states
    prefetch : "http://localhost:3000/all.json"
})
console.log(states)
states.initialize()
$("#prefetch .typehead").typeahead({
    hint : true,
    hightlight : true,
    minLength : 1,

},{
    name : "states",
    source : states,
    display : "name",
    displayKey : "name"
})
```

JSON like this

```
[{"_id":"573ff845d35b36f82c6cc71e","created_at":"2016-05-21T05:55:17.335Z","inc":0,"updated_at":"2016-05-21T05:56:23.569Z","name":"comp1","pizza":"pizza1","ranking":20,"num":3,"__v":0},{"_id":"573ff845d35b36f82c6cc71f","created_at":"2016-05-21T05:55:17.340Z","inc":0,"updated_at":"2016-05-21T05:55:17.340Z","name":"comp2","pizza":"pizza2","ranking":5,"num":1,"__v":0},{"_id":"573ff845d35b36f82c6cc720","created_at":"2016-05-21T05:55:17.342Z","inc":0,"updated_at":"2016-05-21T05:55:17.342Z","name":"comp3","pizza":"pizza3","ranking":10,"num":1,"__v":0}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a `templates` object having a `suggestion` property that is a function returning an `html` string containing suggestion to be displayed.

Substitute `datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace("name")` for `datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace("name")`; add `.ttAdapter()` following setting `states` at `source`.

Not certain which property of object selected, or other `html` should be displayed at suggestion container? Used `pizza` property of selected object at stacksnippets

```js
$(function() {

  var states = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace("name"),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guest271314/"
              + "5b1b22a728f97a8847034c3f9dba69b0/raw/"
              + "fc016e61fed65b45e027837dada9f60e6793bc4b/comp.json"
  });

  states.initialize();

  $("#prefetch.typeahead").typeahead({
    minLength: 1,
    hint: true,
    highlight: true
  }, {
    name: "suggestions",
    display: "name",
    templates: {
      suggestion: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        // set `html` to be displayed at suggestion dropdown
        var suggest = "<li>" + data.pizza + "</li>";
        return suggest
      }
    },
    source: states.ttAdapter()
  });
})
```

```css
div.search {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px;
}
.typeahead,
.tt-query,
.tt-hint {
  border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 24px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  width: 396px;
}
.typeahead {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.typeahead:focus {
  border: 2px solid #0097CF;
}
.tt-query {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
}
.tt-hint {
  color: #999999;
}
.tt-dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-top: 12px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  width: 422px;
}
.tt-suggestion {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 3px 20px;
}
.tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor {
  background-color: #0097CF;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.tt-suggestion p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="search">
  <input type="text" id="prefetch" class="typeahead" placeholder="search" />
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but this isn't working. Just to clarify when you say `/* set data property to render */ ` that means i should use `data.name` to get the values for the `name` key in my jSON? I did that and it's not working. maybe there is something wrong with my JSON and I added the `states.ttAdapter()` and the missing comma before `templates`.

Comment: @jackblank Which property of matched object should be displayed as suggestion?

Comment: @jackblank See updated post. Used `pizza` property of selected object as suggestion displayed

Comment: I see you have a var `arr` there and you are using `local`. I knew how to do it with local. My problem was with getting the data from my API. first I tried using an endpoint that had JSON data that didn't work for me. so I used `fs` to make the JSON file.  It was important that I can get the data from somewhere else and not on the same page. hopefully I can do that with your answer. I'll try it out. Thanks.

Comment: @jackblank _"My problem was with getting the data from my API. first I tried using an endpoint that had JSON data"_ See updated post

Comment: I see it works Thanks. I have a problem though. when I change it to `prefetch : "http://localhost:3000/all.json"` it doesn't work. when I copy and paste that link into the url bar  I see the JSON in the browser so that doesn't make sense to me. It should read the file. I have `all.json` in the public folder. I'll accept this answer but do you have any advice for me about what I mentioned?